# modules installed again and again

Tags: plugin-system, ftplugin

Here is a part of my `ftplugin/fortran_state.vim`

```
" Check python modules and install{{{1
if !executable('fprettify') || !executable('fortls') || !executable('unidecode')
  :let choice =confirm("Some python dependencies doesn't exists! Install them?", "&Yes\n&No(use fallback)")
  if !executable('fprettify')
    :call install_deps#install_fprettify() 
  endif
  if !executable('fortls')
    :call install_deps#install_fortls() 
  endif
  if !executable('unidecode')
    :call install_deps#install_unidecode() 
  endif
endif
"}}}
```

The intention is these block will be executed and install the dependencies only when they are not installed (obviously!)
Problem is, even they are installed and in path, this block is executed every time I open a fortran file.

```
pip3 install --user fortran-language-server fprettify unidecode
Requirement already satisfied: fortran-language-server in ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fprettify in ~.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: unidecode in ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: configargparse in ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fprettify) (1.2.3)


which fprettify 
~/.local/bin/fprettify
which fortls
~/.local/bin/fortls
which unidecode 
~/.local/bin/unidecode
```

One odd thing is installation is going on even if I select `No(Use fallback)`.

The `install_deps` is from `autoload`, with:

```
function! install_deps#install_fprettify()
  echom "Installing fprettify"
  :execute ':!pip3 install fprettify --user -q'
endfunction
function! install_deps#install_unidecode()
  echom "Installing unidecode"
  :execute ':!pip3 install unidecode --user -q'
endfunction
function! install_deps#install_fortls()
  echom "Installing fortls"
  :execute ':!pip3 install fortran-language-server --user -q'
endfunction
```

So,it looks like `if block` and `choice` does not work as I think.

What I am doing wrong here?

**Update**

1. Reply to Mat:
   [image]
2. Reply to Ben:
   I have used:

   ```
    let choice =confirm("Some python dependencies doesn't exists! Install them?", "&Yes\n&No(use fallback)")
    echo choice
   ```

If I chose Yes, confirm is 1, with No, its 2. But, code should not go to `choice` at all when all of them are already installed. Why the code is reading that choice line?

Comment: `:echo $PATH` while inside Vim.

Comment: You haven't checked the return value of `confirm`, have you?

Comment: Note that in `ftplugin/*.vim` you don't need to type the colon before commands (i.e. just `call install_deps#install_fprettify()`, not `:call install_deps#install_fprettify()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, I have found the solution. This is for others reference.
vim probably can not expand `~/` to `$HOME`. In my `.bashrc`, I had

```
PATH="${PATH}:~/bin"
PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"
```

changing that to

```
PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/bin"
PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/.local/bin"
```

solved the problem.